# Cypher Neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am developing some kind of social trivia game where my main DB is Neo4j. I am having a hard time in a specific use-case.

I have Challenge node with two Opponents nodes related:

```
(opponent1)-[:OPPONENT]->(challenge)<-[:OPPONENT]-(opponent2)
```

The Challenge relate to Subject node:

```
challenge-[:subject]->subject
```

Each subject relate to many questions:

```
subject-[:HAS]->question
```

If opponent answered a specific question before the bellow relation will be exist:

```
opponent-[:ANSWER]->question
```

**The use-case:** I need to retrieve X questions (which never been answered by both opponents) for the challenge

I have the following Cypher query:

```
START challenge=node({0}) , subject=node({1}) 
MATCH (opponent1)-[:OPPONENT]->(challenge)<-[:OPPONENT]-(opponent2) 
WITH opponent1,opponent2,subject
MATCH (subject)-[:HAS]->(question) 
WHERE  length(opponent1-[:ANSWER]->question) = 0 and length(opponent2-[:ANSWER]->question) = 0 
return question limit {2}
```

The above query works fine and retrieve the possible questions for the challenge.

The problem is that the questions are retrieved consequently and not randomly.

**Explanation:** Each question related to template node which has category property.

```
question-[:TEMPLATE]->template
```

The questions created in the first place by template which mean all the questions from specific category has sequenced ID in the DB therefore the above query retrieves questions from the same category.

I want to be able to retrieve challenge questions randomly. Also, is the query structure is correct from a performance perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not aware of a native way of how to get a random result, there is smting already asked about it here:
[neo4j: Is there a way/how to select random nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510696/neo4j-is-there-a-way-how-to-select-random-nodes)

about the query, depends on data, but i would try rather this:

```
START challenge=node({0}) , subject=node({1})
MATCH (opponent1)-[:OPPONENT]->(challenge)<-[:OPPONENT]-(opponent2)
WITH opponent1,opponent2,subject
MATCH (subject)-[:HAS]->(question)
WHERE not(opponent1-[:ANSWER]->question) and not (opponent2-[:ANSWER]->question)
return question limit {2}
```

Comment: Hi , thank for the query improvement.. in the link you sent the solution is to perform X queries to get X random questions.. I am looking for one query solution...

Comment: there is no equivalent of psql `order by random()` feature in cypher as far as i know. you can try to get all results and later filter them by random in your latter code

Comment: We wanted to add random() as well as markov() (to return a random path based on weights) as functions in cypher, but haven't done that yet.