# Choosing a random element of a collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What is the best way to randomly select items from a collection?

For example, I'm trying to do this:

```
    match (m:Merchant) return collect(m)[round(rand())]
```

but I get this error, which suggests that round() returns a double:

```
    Type mismatch: expected Integer or Long but was Double (line 1, column 38)
    "match (m:Merchant) return collect(m)[round(rand())] limit 10"
```

I would use the answer provided in this post, [neo4j: Is there a way/how to select random nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510696/neo4j-is-there-a-way-how-to-select-random-nodes) but I don't want consecutive nodes.

Comment: I think that's a bug in `round()`. `RETURN [1,2,3][round(rand())]`, `RETURN [1,2,3][round(0.1)]` and `WITH round(0.1) as x RETURN [1,2,3][x]` all throw that exception, while `RETURN [1,2,3][round(0.1)*1]` works. Same with `floor()`, they just don't return integers. Unless neo folks have other input you might consider raising an issue at github. There's a similar (closed) issue here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/71

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, round should return an integer (tried this, it does indeed give me an integer). Any way, round(rand()) will give you either 0 or 1 right? So perhaps try something like:

```
match (m:Merchant)
with collect(m) as allMerchants, length(collect(m)) as totalMerchants
return allMerchants[round(rand()*(totalMerchants-1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

After some work, I found that you can group the items by rand() and then order by rand.

For example:
       match (m:Merchant) with m, rand() as rand return m order by rand limit 1

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This is more expensive than Luanne's solution.