# Selecting random nodes, neo4j

Tags: neo4j

In order to select random nodes from the graph by using `SKIP` and `random_offset` gets very slow as the value of the `random_offset` increases.

Refer this for the solution by using `SKIP`
[neo4j: Is there a way/how to select random nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510696/neo4j-is-there-a-way-how-to-select-random-nodes)

Is there any alternative way as this is totally inefficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use `rand()` with a WHERE clause as a probability predicate.

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n
WHERE rand() < 0.3 // for a 30% chance to include the node
```

See my blog post on sampling graphs: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/sampling-a-neo4j-database/

Comment: Wouldn't the order of inclusion be alway the same and so making the nodes "at the end of the index" very improbable and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

another alternate solution I came across

START n=node(*)
WHERE n.type='project' AND ID(n)%RANDOM_INT=0
RETURN n